# Extract last regex match in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm using `mutate()` with `str_extract()` to condense a string column in a dataframe to just a single key word column. My problem is that one of the strings contains two keywords, and it's the second one that's more important to me. The regex, though, always takes the first hit it finds to the alternatives I tell it to look for. Is there a way to change this?

MWE (without `mutate()`):

```r
teststring <- "abcdef"
str_extract(teststring, "b|c|a")
```

I'd like to be able to find patterns in the order I choose, not what's first in the test string.

Comment: Maybe `lapply(c("b","c","a"), stringr::str_extract, string=teststring)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the first version is working great, thank you!

Comment: I could not find any duplicates using the "last match regex in R", so even though it is a duplicate it will be a good signpost for the future visitors.

Comment: I didn't even think of it as looking for a last match. Luckily that is what the problem was, and not me trying to find something in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use either [`stringi::stri_extract_last`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/0.2-5/topics/stri_extract_last) or [`stringi::stri_extract_last_regex`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/0.2-5/topics/stri_extract_all_regex) to get the last match:

```
stringi::stri_extract_last_regex('zzzayyyyc.', '[abc]')
stringi::stri_extract_last('zzzayyyyc.', regex=c('[abc]'))
```

See the [R demo online](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikKDMvPdPKCsSIT60oKUpMLonPSSwuiS9KTU@t0FCvqqpKrASCZD11HQX16MSk5Fh1TS7c@tB0gE2xTdaA6dT8/x8A), both return `[1] "c"`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Gki's answer in the comment, if you only want to return the 1st match of your chosen order. we can wrap the code with:

```
teststring <- "ccccbbbaaaaqwerty"

which.min(is.na((sapply(c("b","c","a"), stringr::str_extract, string=teststring))))

b 
1
```

Comment: Thank you! Using this with `mutate()` will only give me the index number back, though.

Comment: I'm not a `dplyr` expert, but if you wrap the code with `names(...)` you will get just the pattern back. perhaps you could implement this?

Comment: Good point, I would have expected that to work but it doesn't give me anything.